# Why is getHibernateTemplate().delete(entity) failing?

Tags: hibernate, spring, transactions

Here is the code:

// Hibernate model

```
@Entity
@Table(name="contact")
public class Contact {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "contact_id")
private Long id;

@Column(name="contact_ref_id")
private String contactRefId;

@Column(name="first_name")
private String firstName;

@Column(name="last_name")
private String lastName;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="app_user_id")
/** user whose contact list owns this contact */
private AppUser appUser;

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}


/**
 * @return AppUser who owns contact list this contact belongs to
 */
public AppUser getAppUser() {
    return appUser;
}

public void setAppUser(AppUser appUser) {
    this.appUser=appUser;
}

public String getContactRefId() {
    return contactRefId;
}

public void setContactRefId(String contactRefId) {
    this.contactRefId=contactRefId;
}
```

}

// DAO layer

```
private Criteria createCriteria() {
    return getHibernateTemplate().getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Contact.class);
}

public void deleteContact(String contactRefId) {
    Criteria criteria = createCriteria();
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("contactRefId", contactRefId));
    Contact contact = (Contact)criteria.uniqueResult();
    try {
        contact = getHibernateTemplate().merge(contact);
        getHibernateTemplate().delete(contact);
    } catch (DataAccessException e) {
        log.error(e.getMessage());
        throw e;
    }
}
```

// Service layer

```
public void deleteContact(String contactRefId) {
    contactDao.delete(contactRefId);
}
```

// Unit test

```
@Test
public void testDeleteContact() {
    contactService.deleteContact("fe43b43a-d77f-45ce-b024-bb6e93264a69");
}
```

// Spring config

```
<beans>
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="model.hibernate"/>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <value>
            hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect
            hibernate.query.substitutions=true 'Y', false 'N'
            hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache=true
            hibernate.cache.provider_class=org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider
        </value>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- Transaction manager for a single Hibernate SessionFactory (alternative to JTA) -->
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="contactsDao" class="ContactDaoHibernate">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<aop:config>
  <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice" pointcut="execution(* service..*.*(..))" order="0"/>
</aop:config>

<!-- Enable @Transactional support -->
<tx:annotation-driven/>

<!-- Enable @AspectJ support -->
  <aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true" />

  <tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="transactionManager">
    <tx:attributes>
       <tx:method name="*"/>
    </tx:attributes>
  </tx:advice>
</beans>
```

When I fire the test method, no exceptions are thrown, but the row in the db is not deleted. Examination of the Contact object in the debugger after it's fetched from the db by criteria.uniqueResult() reveals the complete and correct object was fetched. Although the merge call may appear unneccesary, I did that to see if there was an issue w/ the wrong Session being used for the delete.

It appears therefore that the the delete is not being called in a transaction, although the Spring config is simple and I don't see any potential issues. What is most perplexing is that this DAO code works:

```
public void addContact(Contact contact) {
    try {
        getHibernateTemplate().save(contact);
    } catch (DataAccessException e) {
        log.error(e.getMessage());
        throw e;
    }
}
```

I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's highly recommended to implement `equals()` and `hashCode()` for your object since you seem to use separate sessions for each operation.

See http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/persistent-classes.html#persistent-classes-equalshashcode

---

Update

It appears that your Spring based unit test does not commit transaction. By default Spring test framework will rollback transaction that it started.

Comment: If you use Spring transactional tests, transaction by default rolls back after test. Not sure if that's the problem. I would suggest enabling Hibernate logging and see if delete statement is generated.

Comment: Hmmm I wonder if that's it. We're using Spring for DI in the JUnits but I can't find anything in the Spring config that relates to making tests transactional. The base test class is annotated @TestExecutionListeners({DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class}) but the docs say nothing about that making tests transactional.

Comment: Ah that was it! Our base test class is derived from AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests. Tnx a million!

Comment: By the way, in your sample I don't see anything that would instantiate your service. So you may want to put breakpoint or dump stack inside your service method to see if it actually got proxied by aspectj.

Comment: Ok, I guess my last comment is irrelevant no :) Good Luck!

Comment: And don't hesitate to accept the answer (as well as answers of other people to your questions).

Comment: yeah didn't realize you wrote the original answer too.